# Как правильно получить значение из С в golang?

Tags: c, golang

Пытаюсь сделать конвертор из flow-tools на golang для сбора статистики, но CGO даётся очень тяжело,
установил **flow-tools-dev** для вызова функций. В данный момент имею такой код (ниже) , он только для теcтирования вызова функций, мне необходимо лишь вытащить адреса порты и количество байт, нашёл в сети код на СИ для конвертирования, подскажите как правильно конвертировать из **char *s** в uint32 как это делается ниже в цикле **while()** только для Go.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "ftlib.h"
/* $Id: $ */
 
 
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
  unsigned long fromAddr;
  unsigned long toAddr;
  short int fromIface;
  short int toIface;
  short int fromPort;
  short int toPort;
  unsigned long amount;
} bitel;
 
 
/* parameters
* dstfile router_ip [dstfile router] sb srcfile [srcfile..] 
*/
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 0;
  int fd = 0;
  int str_count = 0;
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *out;
  struct ftio ftio;
  struct ftprof ftp;
  struct fts3rec_offsets fo;
  struct ftver ftv;
  char *rec;
  u_int32 last_time;
  u_int32 tm;
  bitel b_rec;
 
  if (argc < 3)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s out_file in_file1 in_file2 in_file3 ... \n",
               argv[0]);
      return 1;
    }
  if ((out = fopen (argv[1], "wb")) == NULL)
    {
      perror ("Cannot create file %m");
      return 2;
    }
 
  for (i = 2; i < argc; i++)
    {
      if ((fp = fopen (argv[i], "rb")) == NULL)
        {
          perror ("Cannot open file %m");
          return 1;
        }
      fd = fileno (fp);
 
      fterr_setid (argv[0]);
      ftprof_start (&ftp);
      if (ftio_init (&ftio, fd, FT_IO_FLAG_READ) < 0)
        {
          perror ("Error in initialization ftio structure:%m");
          return 0;
        }
 
      ftio_get_ver (&ftio, &ftv);
      fts3rec_compute_offsets (&fo, &ftv);
 
      last_time = 0;
      while ( (rec = ftio_read (&ftio)) )
        {
          str_count++;
          tm = *((u_int32 *) (rec + fo.unix_secs));
          if (last_time != tm)
            {
              b_rec.fromAddr = 0;
              b_rec.toAddr = 0;
              b_rec.fromIface = htons (0xff77);
              b_rec.toIface = htons (0xff77);
              b_rec.fromPort = htons ((u_int16) ((tm >> 16) & 0xFFFF));
              b_rec.toPort = htons ((u_int16) (tm & 0xFFFF));
              b_rec.amount = 0;
              fwrite (&b_rec, sizeof (bitel), 1, out);
              last_time = tm;
            }
          b_rec.fromAddr = htonl (*((u_int32 *) (rec + fo.srcaddr)));
          b_rec.toAddr = htonl (*((u_int32 *) (rec + fo.dstaddr)));
          b_rec.fromIface = htons (*((u_int16 *) (rec + fo.input)));
          b_rec.toIface = htons (*((u_int16 *) (rec + fo.output)));
          b_rec.fromPort = htons (*((u_int16 *) (rec + fo.srcport)));
          b_rec.toPort = htons (*((u_int16 *) (rec + fo.dstport)));
          b_rec.amount = htonl (*((u_int32 *) (rec + fo.dOctets)));
          fwrite (&b_rec, sizeof (bitel), 1, out);
        }
      ftio_close (&ftio);
      fclose (fp);
    }
  fclose (out);
  fprintf (stderr, "Total lines: %d\n", str_count);
  return 0;
}
```

```
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/lib -lft -lz
#include "ftlib.h"
void ftio_get_ver(struct ftio *ftio, struct ftver *ver);
int ftio_init(struct ftio *ftio, int fd, int flag);
int fts3rec_compute_offsets(struct fts3rec_offsets *o, struct ftver *ftv);
void *ftio_read(struct ftio *ftio);
 */
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "unsafe"
)

const FT_IO_FLAG_READ = 0x4  /* stream is open for reading */

func main() {
    path := "/var/log/netflows/2019/2019-01/2019-01-30/ft-v05.2019-01-30.000500+0400"
    ftio := C.struct_ftio{}
    ftv := C.struct_ftver{}
    fo  := C.struct_fts3rec_offsets{}
    f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_RDONLY, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    C.ftio_init(&ftio,C.int(f.Fd()),FT_IO_FLAG_READ)
    C.fts3rec_compute_offsets(&fo,&ftv)
    for i := 0;i < 5; i++{
        rec := C.ftio_read(&ftio)
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n",(*C.uint32_t)(*(*unsafe.Pointer)(rec)))

    }
}
```

Comment: В программе на Си (если я правильно понимаю, вас интересует фрагмент `tm = *((u_int32 *) (rec + fo.unix_secs));`) **нет конвертации**.  Тут 4 байта с адреса `(rec + fo.unix_secs)`, содержащие целое число без знака, перемещаются в переменную `tm` / Я не знаком с GO, поэтому не знаю, как в нем работать напрямую с памятью (зная адреса, читать-писать байты по ним). Надеюсь, в этом языке такая возможность есть. Если нет, то возможно вы можете вызывать функции, написанные на Си и использовать возвращаемое ими значение?

Comment: @avp Да я могу их вызывать и использовать возвращаемое значение, но оно у меня теперь типа ```unsafe.Pointer```, соответственно теперь мне его и необходимо преобразовать. Вот в этом и проблема не знаю как правильно это сделать.

Comment: imho проще всего будет, если Сишная функция будет возвращать число (скажем, uin32_t), расположенное по данному адресу. Тогда проблем с `unsafe.Pointer` не будет. Если в вашей программе нужно будет манипулировать адресами, то наверное тип `uint64_t` (я не знаю его аналога в GO) для адреса подойдет